# C++ inheritance design

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I am writing a c++ for portfolio management.  In this case some of the equities can from a retirement portfolio, and the remaining equities are on the open market.
  My general plan is to have the data in the following classes.

```
class Equity { private:  std::string name, exchange, symbol };
class EquityHistory : public Equity { private std::list<DateRecord> history };
class YahooDAO {};
class RetirementDAO {};
class Portfolio { private: std::list<EquityHistory> equities; }
```

In the main, or upper level class, the portfolio is populated with a list of equities.  The DAO classes provide for obtaining the price history from the web.  The question I have is how to have the Portfolio class call the correct DAO class, depending on the exchange.

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information to answer this, currently.  What is the relationship between the `DAO` objects and the other classes?  Do they inherit from a common base class?

Comment: `std::vector` is almost always preferred over `std::list`

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your two data providers in a third one that will redirect depending on the exchange.

This way from the point of view of the folio all is abstract, it does not know the data source, and if later you decide to change the way you fetch data you won't have to update the *Portfolio* class.

Here is the idea:

```
class DAO
{
    private: YahooDAO* yahoo, RetirementDAO* retirement;

    public: DAO()
    {
        yahoo = new YahooDAO();
        retirement = new RetirementDAO();
    }

    public: std::List<Data> getData(EquityHistory* equity)
    {
        std::List<Data> data;

        if (equity->exchange = "some exchange")
        {
            data = yahoo->getData(equity);
        }
        else if (equity->exchange = "another exchange")
        {
            data = retirement->getData(equity);
        }

        return data;
    }
};

class Portfolio
{
    private: std::list<EquityHistory> equities;
    private: DAO* dao;

    public: Portfolio(DAO* dao)
    {
        this->dao = dao;
    }

    public: void loadData()
    {
        ...
        std::List<Data> data = dao->getData(equity);
        ...
    }
};
```

If you need you can abstract the *getData* method using an interface *IDataSource*.

Comment: Why instantiate both if you're only using one? Also, this isn't very open to extension. What would happen if the need arises and we need to add a DAO method?

Comment: @IBY: this is just the idea without all the fluff, so instantiation could of course be done lazily but that's more code not to the point. I don't get your second point: if the need arise we'll have to update the code anyway, could you extend on this point please? :)

Comment: Adding a new method would require changing existing code and writing a lot of boilerplate. This is what we're trying to avoid with object oriented design.

Comment: Please be more precise by giving a concrete example; because OO design won't prevent adding a new method if you need a new feature. e.g. if I need a "get data in an asynchronous manner" feature I'll add it to DAO, as a "getDataAsync" method that will either trigger a thread or rely on the possible async capabilities of the two underlying DAOs. And as I've said if you want more design coolness you can add some interfaces but here this is clearly useless: if I have a third provider, say Bloomberg, it will be hidden and used in a transparent manner inside my concrete DAO class.